# slds-gutters not adding spacing between div's

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, slds, slds-grid

The slds-gutters class does not seem to add spacing between the div's. What is the reason for this? Essentially I could add padding, but I would like to understand why there is no spacing between the div's when using slds-gutters. I've provided an image for reference. Is gutters not the equivalent of gap in cssgrid?

[image]

**MARKUP**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">    

<p>Grid App</p>    

<!-- 4 div's with spacing between eachother -->
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
  <div style="background-color:green;" class="slds-col">
    <span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:yellow;" class="slds-col">
    <span>2</span>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:green;" class="slds-col">
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color:yellow;" class="slds-col">
    <span>4</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not the same as the CSS gap. Instead, it provides an additional 12px of [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) on the left and right sides, which appears inside the div's box. Here's your example, modified to show the difference:

[image: Comparison of slds-gutter]

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <h1>With Gutters</h1>
    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
        <div style="background: pink" class="slds-col">
            <span>1</span>
        </div>
        <div style="background: lightblue" class="slds-col">
            <span>2</span>
        </div>
        <div style="background: pink" class="slds-col">
            <span>3</span>
        </div>
        <div style="background: lightblue" class="slds-col">
            <span>4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Without Gutters</h1>
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div style="background: pink" class="slds-col">
            <span>1</span>
        </div>
        <div style="background: lightblue" class="slds-col">
            <span>2</span>
        </div>
        <div style="background: pink" class="slds-col">
            <span>3</span>
        </div>
        <div style="background: lightblue" class="slds-col">
            <span>4</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work (I am not sure why the original code does not add the padding).

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">    

<p>Grid App</p>    

<!-- 4 div's with spacing between eachother -->
<div class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
  <div class="slds-col">
    <div style="background-color:green;">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-col">
    <div style="background-color:yellow;">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-col">
    <div style="background-color:green;">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-col">
    <div style="background-color:yellow;">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```